# How do I design a custom Android control and use it in Xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-custom-view

I understand how to create a custom Android control, and I believe I understand how to pull attributes for it from the Xml layout. I don't know, however, how to get any children elements from it.

Here's a visual example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
public class Menu extends LinearLayout
{
    // Custom Code
}

public class MenuItem extends Button
{
    // Custom Code
}

<!-- Layout -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Menu>
    <MenuItem/>
    <MenuItem/>
</Menu>
```

When my Menu is created, how do I get references to the two MenuItems?

Comment: "When my Menu is created, how do I get references to the two MenuItems?" Just give them an `android:id` attribute, I guess. I feel like I must be misunderstanding your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an `android:id` to do that. If you will not know how many childs you will have:

`LinearLayout` extends [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html), so you can use `getChildAt()` and `getChildCount()`  to get those views.

Comment: I'll now how many children are in the Menu because I'll add them to the Xml, but I want this to be dynamic enough that I don't need to know. I'll give getChildCount() a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for accesing any control (custom or system ) an id is a must. by specifying an id you give it a unique identity. Using this id you can get a reference to that control.